# CONCAT rows and return within GROUP

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation

I have the following [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c5e4/13), i can group the results by time, count and name, but i also want to return the error_strings within the same row.

Any suggestions? Group concat didnt really do what i needed.

I'd like the output to look like:

```
NAME | TIME | TODAYSCOUNT  | ERRORS
------------------------------------
A     1111           2000  error1,erro2
B     1111             20  error1,erro2
C     1111             10  error1,erro2
D     1111              3  error1,erro2
```

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? What are you trying to do that group_concat doesn't accomplish?

Comment: May be you could show us the sample output you want.

Comment: we also need your sample output.

Comment: How does that sample output relate to the table data?  Not only do the error strings appear truncated, but it isn't clear what `TODAYSCOUNT` is or how the records have been grouped.  Please clarify.

Comment: Like i said, it's just a sample. If i knew how to do it, i wouldn't have truncated the errors. Todays count is time 1111, and yesterdays count is 3111 as an exmaple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the below:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c5e4/20

```
SELECT name,time,count(*) as todaycount, group_concat(error_str) as errors  
FROM test 
GROUP BY Name,time
```

You could change to

```
group_concat(distinct error_str)
```

for distinct error string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6929/2

I took it one step forward as it looked like you might take it this far:

```
SELECT Name, FROM_UNIXTIME('%m-%d-%Y', SUM(TodaysDate)),FROM_UNIXTIME('%m-%d-%Y',SUM(YesterdaysDate)), sum(TodaysCount),Sum(YesterdaysCount),CONCAT(String),CONCAT(String2)
FROM (
    SELECT Name,Time as TodaysDate,0 as YesterdaysDate,COUNT(*) as TodaysCount, 0 as YesterdaysCount,GROUP_CONCAT(error_str) as String, '' as String2
    FROM Test
    WHERE Time = 3111
    GROUP BY Name
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Name,0 as TodaysDate,Time as YesterdaysDate,0 as TodaysCount, COUNT(*)  as YesterdaysCount, '' as String, GROUP_CONCAT(error_str) as String2
    FROM Test
    WHERE Time = 1111
    GROUP BY Name
  ) as t
GROUP BY Name
```

The above used unions